# Implementing Custom Back Navigation in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, onbackpressed

I am trying to implement custom back navigation in my fragment based on the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#implement_custom_back_navigation)

But when I try to replace the "// Handle the back button event" bit with my back button evet code, my IDE throws up an error saying "Required: OnBackPressedCallback found () -> OnBackPressedCallback"

I am using appcompat:1.0.2. and I have core-ktx:1.0.2'.

> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
>
> implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'

Here is how I am trying to implement the onBackPressedDispatcher

```
val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
        patientsActivity.moveToLoginScreen(true) // <-- thing I want to happen when the back button is pressed
    }
```

What am I missing here? How do I go about implementing custom back navigation?

Comment: could you show the code, this is probably just a syntax error

Comment: And include your `build.gradle` - note that Kotlin snippets assume you are using the `-ktx` artifacts of the related libraries

Comment: @JianAstrero I am getting the error in the "patientsActivity.moveToLoginScreen(true)"

Comment: @ianhanniballake let me know if you need to see all of my build.gradle file

Comment: It's probably safer to override `onBackPressed` in your Activity instead.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - not overriding `onBackPressed()` is exactly why this new API was created. There's no reason to do that when you're using the new API.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code is not on the gradle files but on the syntax. The documentation does not provide the proper kotlin code that corresponds to the java code that was given.

Here is the propper way of creating an object of an abstract class - OnBackPressedCallback

```
val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        patientsActivity.moveToLoginScreen(true)
    }
})
```

support a change in the documentation here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135469965

Comment: The documentation is for the [Kotlin extension](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher#extension-functions), which is correct.

Comment: It is not. on back pressed dispatcher is an abstract class and not an interface. you cant implement it like that. can you read kotlin code?

Comment: The Kotlin extension takes a lambda with receiver, not an instance of `OnBackPressedCallback`. You absolutely can write exactly that code in the documentation if you use the Kotlin extension. You can see the same syntax from the documentation in the [tests for the Kotlin extension](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/activity/activity-ktx/src/androidTest/java/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcherTest.kt#91).

Comment: I ended up using both your answers. I needed the fragment-ktx: import (why isn't this documented???) and creating an object of OnBackPressedCallback. Can I mark both of them as correct ?

Comment: The exact syntax in the documentation works fine - make sure you have actually imported the Kotlin extension.

Answer (score 1):

`OnBackPressedDispatcher` is part of the new `androidx.activity` dependency. The best way to gain access to the new library is to upgrade your version of Fragments:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-beta01"
```

By using the `fragment-ktx` artifact, you also will gain a transitive dependency on `activity-ktx`, which is what has the Kotlin extension that the documentation uses.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you need `import androidx.activity.addCallback` and in your app build.gradle, `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-beta01"`

Comment: Please show the added code in context of the original request - that way the solution will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed the boolean argument and that is why it doesn't work. The right code is as shown in [Jian Astrero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640729/implementing-custom-back-navigation-in-android/63395687#answer-56641415). Alternatively, you can use the lambda syntax like this:

```
val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, true) {
    patientsActivity.moveToLoginScreen(true)
}
```

Note that the **true** passed as second parameter is essential for it to work.

Comment: The real problem is that kotlin extension isn't imported. The Boolean parameter has default value `true` https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/package-summary#(androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher).addCallback(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)